# How to print all the distinct possible palindromic strings formed using characters of a given string

Tags: c++, string, palindrome

**input** - "sasank"
**output** - {'s', 'a', 'n', 'k', 'aa', 'ss', 'sas', 'asa' ,'saas', 'assa','aka', 'ana', .......}

we can select characters from any position of a string and combine to form a palindromic string.I have solved palindromic substring problem but unable to develop a logic for this program.

Comment: Well how would you do it by hand?  Start there and see where it leads you.

Comment: Do consider that you will have to produce permutations of the input strings characters, but you can eliminate some permutations based on how many of the letter there are: Any palindrome has at most ONE single occurrence of a particular letter. So track how many times each letter occurs in the input string, and based on that, produce your permutations. Problem solved.

Comment: Some values are missing (`"ana"`, `"aka"`, ...), else I don't understand from where `"saas"` and `"assa"` come.

Comment: @Jarod42 - Yeah!! I edited my question output .... {"ana',"aka"...} should be in output.

Comment: @MatsPetersson - Thanks for the explaination.I got some idea. Let me try to write the code first.